# Можно ли в python разбить одно пространство имён на несколько файлов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В других языках, я знаю, можно, создавать одно пространство имён, и раскидывать его по разным файлам.

А в питоне не слышал, о такой возможности.
Может я что-то упустил, и на самом деле такая возможность есть?
Если же нет, то по какой причине? Хотелось бы узнать.

**Чтобы не было споров по поводу надобности сего, приведу в пример цитату из книги "алгоритмы и структуры данных":**

> Пространство имен (namespace) является абстракцией более высокого
>   уровня, поскольку, в общем случае, одно пространство имен может
>   объединять объекты, определенные в разных файлах, с другой стороны, в
>   одном файле могут быть определены объекты из нескольких пространств
>   имен. Таким образом, концепции физической и логической модульности
>   являются ортогональными.

Comment: Не нужно это, ибо в больших проектах станет нетрудно запутаться. Но если очень хочется, то наверно можно через `exec` (но всё равно не нужно)

Answer (score 4):

Да можно, используя пакеты.

Пример:

package/__init__.py

```
from .one import func
from .two import func2
```

package/one.py

```
def func():
    pass
```

package/two.py

```
def func2():
    pass
```

Использование:

```
import package
package.func()
package.func2()
```

Comment: Я чего-то не понимаю? Мне кажется, что это не совсем то, о чём речь, так-как всё-таки каждый файл локализует в себе отдельное пространство имён.

Comment: @МистерФикс одно пространство имён: `package`. Как функции используются извне и как они реализованы—это разные вещи. Посмотрит на [`asyncio/__init__.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/__init__.py).

Comment: это только снаружи. Как насчёт использования функции из two непосредственно в one? Придётся импортировать? Зачем, они же в "одном namespace"

Comment: @vp_arth, смотря какую проблему пытается решить автор вопроса. Если "чтобы было" точно так же, как в каком-то другом языке - не получится, у всех языков свои нюансы. По поводу использования функций one из модуля two - да, придется импортировать. Нет, модули друг для друга не в одном namespace. Но почему внешнего наблюдателя (пользователя пакета) должны волновать детали реализации?

Comment: В общем, ваш ответ не про `разбить одно на несколько файлов`, а про `объединить несколько в одно`. Тоже полезно знать, не спорю.

Comment: модуль `package.one` внутри `package/__init__.py` следует как `from .one import func` импортировать (неявные относительные импорты не работают в Python 3).

Comment: @vp_arth: можно использовать, просто в one.py импортируете желаемый модуль: `from . import two` и используете нужные функции.

Comment: @insolor, это должно волновать разработчика, а не пользователя. То есть реально такой возможности нет? Добавьте тогда такой ответ, чтобы я мог отметить его как правильный.

Comment: @МистерФикс "принятый" ответ не обязан быть "правильным". Это просто ответ, который автору вопроса помог (по мнению автора). Это в туре написано (присоединяйтесь к ~20% пользователей, которые получили знак, за проход тура: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @jfs Дословно: _Принятие ответа не означает, что он лучший; это значит, что изложенное в нём решение помогло автору вопроса._

Comment: @jfs Мне помог ответ, что такой возможности нет. Но я не могу его отметить, так как он в комментариях.

Comment: @МистерФикс вы сказали: "чтобы я мог отметить его как правильный". Я сказал: "принятый ответ не обязан быть правильным" (что как вы убедились согласуется с документацией).  Я не знаю как ещё выразить мысль, что принятие вами ответа не сделает его правильным. Кстати, вы можете свой ответ оставить (и принять его, если хотите), если думаете что нашли решение.